I need advice with data manipulation R: large data set
I have two data sets of bird detections. One by a human at randomly selected intervals of 2 minutes and one by a machine. I want to compare how well the machine did by checking if the detections coincide with the researcher's. The data looks like this:
Researcher detections: 

common_me                   file_me                start_2min   end_2min
Amazonian Motmot            SMM04873_20220821_051902    22          24
Black-capped Becard         SMM04873_20220821_051902    22          24
Black-tailed Leaftosser     SMM04873_20220821_051902    22          24
Bright-rumped Attila        SMM04873_20220821_051902    22          24
Chestnut-tailed Antbird     SMM04873_20220821_051902    22          24
Cinereous Timou             SMM04873_20220821_051902    22          24
Dusky-throated Antshrike    SMM04873_20220821_051902    22          24
Amazonian Motmot            SMM04873_20220822_051902    21          23
Amazonian Motmot            SMM04893_20220814_171502    27          29
Blue-headed Parrot          SMM04893_20220814_171502    27          29
Broad-billed Motmot         SMM04893_20220814_171502    27          29
Elegant Woodcreeper         SMM04893_20220814_171502    27          29
Amazonian Motmot            SMM04919_20220815_044502    47          49
Amazonian Motmot            SMM04919_20220816_162502    54          56
Amazonian Motmot            SMM04919_20220823_045002    35          37
Amazonian Pygmy-owl         SMM04873_20220821_041903    19          21
Amazonian Pygmy-owl         SMM04873_20220902_184802    42          44
Sclater's Antwren           SMM04873_20220813_091702    52          54    

I have over 500 rows of researcher detections. Start_2min marks how many minutes after the hour the machine started recording when a bird was detected. The recorder name (SMM04873), date (20220821) and hour (051902) appear in the file_me SMM04873_20220821_051902. The first row shows that an Amazonian Motmot was detected in the interval 22-24 (22 minutes after 05:19:02)
The machine data looks like this:

common_me                       file_me                    start    end actual_time_last
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper    SMM04873_20220902_044803    1893    1896    05:19:36
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper    SMM04873_20220902_044803    1929    1932    05:20:12
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper    SMM04873_20220910_045802    1542    1545    05:23:44
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper    SMM04879_20220825_172502    1341    1344    17:47:23
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper    SMM04879_20220825_172502    1344    1347    17:47:26
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper    SMM04879_20220910_144702    1380    1383    15:10:02
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper    SMM04893_20220812_171502    1773    1776    17:44:35
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper    SMM04893_20220812_171502    1818    1821    17:45:20
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper    SMM04893_20220813_171502    1911    1914    17:46:53
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper    SMM04893_20220813_171502    1926    1929    17:47:08
Sclater's Antwren.              SMM04873_20220813_091702    3180    3183    10:10:02

In this case, start is the seconds after the machine started recording that a bird was detected. I have calculated the actual time of this detection happened, column actual_time_last.
I need to see if the machine detected the same species during the intervals the researcher verified them.
For example, the last one Sclater's Antwren was detected by the machine as 10:10:02 and by the researcher in the interval covering that time, in the hour 9:17:02 minute 52 to 54 (10:09:02 - 10:11:02). I need to end up with a data frame that looks like this (or similar):
species             machine researcher  file_name                   min_start   min_end
Sclater's Antwren   yes     yes         SMM04873_20220813_091702    52          54


I have been trying to accomplish this for days and am not embarassed to say even using ChatGPT but I have not managed to get this done. The machine data has over 100k rows so it's an insane amount of data to handle and the computer often crashes.
Any help on how I could accomplish this with R would be very welcomed!

Please provide workable datasets, e.g. by using dput. With no data, one can suggest some approaches, but either they would been untested, or it would take some time to come up with mock data, that might or might not properly mimic yours.

My approach would be to put all timestamps on the same timeline (i.e. parse the file names with strptime, and add start and end times) to get actual start and end times, and then check for time overlaps. There are a few questions here regarding this last part.

This sounds like you're looking for a non-equi join, specifically looking for overlaps, e.g. data.table::foverlaps

You need to ensure that the species names match between the two datasets. I removed the dot in "Sclater's Antwren."
The task is pretty easy and fast with package data.table:
library(data.table)
researchers <- fread("common_me,                   file_me,                start_2min,   end_2min
Amazonian Motmot,            SMM04873_20220821_051902,    22,          24
Black-capped Becard,        SMM04873_20220821_051902,    22,          24
Black-tailed Leaftosser,     SMM04873_20220821_051902,    22,          24
Bright-rumped Attila,        SMM04873_20220821_051902,    22,          24
Chestnut-tailed Antbird,     SMM04873_20220821_051902,    22,          24
Cinereous Timou,             SMM04873_20220821_051902,    22,          24
Dusky-throated Antshrike,    SMM04873_20220821_051902,    22,          24
Amazonian Motmot,            SMM04873_20220822_051902,    21,          23
Amazonian Motmot,            SMM04893_20220814_171502,    27,          29
Blue-headed Parrot,          SMM04893_20220814_171502,    27,          29
Broad-billed Motmot,         SMM04893_20220814_171502,    27,          29
Elegant Woodcreeper,         SMM04893_20220814_171502,    27,          29
Amazonian Motmot,            SMM04919_20220815_044502,    47,          49
Amazonian Motmot,            SMM04919_20220816_162502,    54,          56
Amazonian Motmot,            SMM04919_20220823_045002,    35,          37
Amazonian Pygmy-owl,         SMM04873_20220821_041903,    19,          21
Amazonian Pygmy-owl,         SMM04873_20220902_184802,    42,          44
Sclater's Antwren,           SMM04873_20220813_091702,    52,          54  ")

#setDT(researchers) #if you imported the data differently

researchers[, c("id", "date", "time") := tstrsplit(file_me, "_")]
researchers[, datetime := as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), format = "%Y%m%d %H%M%S", tz = "UTC")]
researchers[, c("start", "end") := .(datetime + start_2min * 60,
                                     datetime + end_2min * 60)]

machine <- fread("common_me,                       file_me,                    start,    end, actual_time_last
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper,    SMM04873_20220902_044803,    1893,    1896,    05:19:36
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper,   SMM04873_20220902_044803,    1929,   1932,    05:20:12
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper,    SMM04873_20220910_045802,    1542,    1545,    05:23:44
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper,    SMM04879_20220825_172502,    1341,    1344,    17:47:23
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper,    SMM04879_20220825_172502,    1344,    1347,    17:47:26
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper,    SMM04879_20220910_144702,    1380,    1383,    15:10:02
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper,    SMM04893_20220812_171502,    1773,    1776,    17:44:35
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper,    SMM04893_20220812_171502,    1818,    1821,    17:45:20
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper,    SMM04893_20220813_171502,    1911,    1914,    17:46:53
Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper,    SMM04893_20220813_171502,    1926,    1929,    17:47:08
Sclater's Antwren,              SMM04873_20220813_091702,    3180,    3183,    10:10:02")

machine[, c("id", "date", "time") := tstrsplit(file_me, "_")]
machine[, datetime := as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), format = "%Y%m%d %H%M%S", tz = "UTC")]
machine[, c("start", "end") := .(datetime + start,
                                     datetime + end)]

"I need to see if the machine detected the same species during the intervals the researcher verified them."
setkey(researchers, common_me, id, start, end)
setkey(machine, common_me, id, start, end)

overlaps <- foverlaps(machine, researchers, type = "any", nomatch = NULL)
machine[, overlap := FALSE]
machine[overlaps, overlap := TRUE]
# Key: <common_me, id, start, end>
#                        common_me                  file_me               start                 end actual_time_last       id     date   time            datetime overlap
#                           <char>                   <char>              <POSc>              <POSc>           <char>   <char>   <char> <char>              <POSc>  <lgcl>
#  1: Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper SMM04873_20220902_044803 2022-09-02 05:19:36 2022-09-02 05:19:39         05:19:36 SMM04873 20220902 044803 2022-09-02 04:48:03   FALSE
#  2: Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper SMM04873_20220902_044803 2022-09-02 05:20:12 2022-09-02 05:20:15         05:20:12 SMM04873 20220902 044803 2022-09-02 04:48:03   FALSE
#  3: Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper SMM04873_20220910_045802 2022-09-10 05:23:44 2022-09-10 05:23:47         05:23:44 SMM04873 20220910 045802 2022-09-10 04:58:02   FALSE
#  4: Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper SMM04879_20220825_172502 2022-08-25 17:47:23 2022-08-25 17:47:26         17:47:23 SMM04879 20220825 172502 2022-08-25 17:25:02   FALSE
#  5: Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper SMM04879_20220825_172502 2022-08-25 17:47:26 2022-08-25 17:47:29         17:47:26 SMM04879 20220825 172502 2022-08-25 17:25:02   FALSE
#  6: Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper SMM04879_20220910_144702 2022-09-10 15:10:02 2022-09-10 15:10:05         15:10:02 SMM04879 20220910 144702 2022-09-10 14:47:02   FALSE
#  7: Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper SMM04893_20220812_171502 2022-08-12 17:44:35 2022-08-12 17:44:38         17:44:35 SMM04893 20220812 171502 2022-08-12 17:15:02   FALSE
#  8: Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper SMM04893_20220812_171502 2022-08-12 17:45:20 2022-08-12 17:45:23         17:45:20 SMM04893 20220812 171502 2022-08-12 17:15:02   FALSE
#  9: Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper SMM04893_20220813_171502 2022-08-13 17:46:53 2022-08-13 17:46:56         17:46:53 SMM04893 20220813 171502 2022-08-13 17:15:02   FALSE
# 10: Amazonian Barred-Woodcreeper SMM04893_20220813_171502 2022-08-13 17:47:08 2022-08-13 17:47:11         17:47:08 SMM04893 20220813 171502 2022-08-13 17:15:02   FALSE
# 11:            Sclater's Antwren SMM04873_20220813_091702 2022-08-13 10:10:02 2022-08-13 10:10:05         10:10:02 SMM04873 20220813 091702 2022-08-13 09:17:02    TRUE

